# On proving a result on the eigenvalues of a projection matrix on least-squares method

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares

Let $A$ be a real $m \times n$ matrix with $m \geq n$ and $\mbox{rank}(A) = n$.

In the least-squares theory, the pseudo-inverse of $A$ is defined as
$$
A^\dagger = (A^T A)^{-1} A^T
$$

It is easy to verify that
$$
A^\dagger A = I
$$

Thus, if we define $P$ as
$$
P = A A^\dagger,
$$
then $P$ is a real $m \times m$ matrix and
$$
P^2 = P
$$

Thus, $P$ is a projection matrix.

(If $\mathbf{x} = A c$ for any vector $c$, then $P \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x}$.)

Also, if we define $M$ as
$$
M = I - P,
$$
then it is easy to check that $M^2 = M$. Hence, $M$ is also a projection matrix.

(For any vector $\mathbf{x} = A \mathbf{c}$, $M \mathbf{x} = (I - P) \mathbf{x} = 0$.)

Let $(\lambda, \mathbf{x})$ be any eigenpair of $P$. Then
$$
P \mathbf{x} = \lambda \mathbf{x}
$$

Multiplying by $P$, we get
$$
P^2 \mathbf{x} = \lambda P \mathbf{x} = \lambda \cdot \lambda \mathbf{x}
$$

Since $P^2 = P$, we get
$$
P \mathbf{x} = \lambda \mathbf{x} = \lambda^2 \mathbf{x}
$$

Since $\mathbf{x} \neq 0$, we must have
$$
\lambda = \lambda^2 \ \ \mbox{or} \ \ \lambda (\lambda - 1) = 0
$$

Thus, the eigenvalues of the projection matrix $P$ are $0$ and $1$.

Similarly, we can show that the eigenvalues of the projection matrix $M = I - P$ are
also $0$ and $1$.

In a text-book titled "Advanced Econometrics" by Takeshi Amemiya (1985, Harvard University Press), the author mentions the result in the Appendix of the book which states:

1. The eigenvalues of the projection matrix $P$ consist of $n$ ones and $m - n$ zeroes.
2. The eigenvalues of the projection matrix $M = I - P$ consist of $m - n$ ones and $n$ zeros.

I like to know how to prove the results 1) and 2) on the multiplicity of the eigenvalues of $P$ and $M$.

I tried to work out a proof and I outline my results for (1). [Proving (2) is similar!]

We note that
$$
P = A A^\dagger
$$
where $A^\dagger$ is the pseudo-inverse of $A$.

Hence,
$$
\mbox{rank}(P) = \mbox{rank}(A) = n
$$
($A$ is an overdetermined $m \times n$ matrix with $m \geq n$, $\mbox{rank}(A) = n$.)

We know that
$$
\mbox{rank}(P) + \mbox{nullity}(P) = m
$$
which gives
$$
\mbox{nullity}(P) = m - n
$$

Since the null-space of $P$ coincides with the eigenspace of the eigenvalue $0$ of $P$,
we conclude that the eigenvalues of $P$ has $(m - n)$ zeros.

Since $P$ has only 0 and 1 as the eigenvalues, it will follow that the eigenvalues of $P$ has $n$ ones.

In a similar way, it can be shown that the eigenvalues of $M = I - P$ has $n$ zeros and $(m - n)$ ones.

I tried this calculation as a draft for the "proof". Your comments are welcome.

Comment: you indicated that:   $A$ be a real $m \times n$ matrix with $m \geq n$ and $\mbox{rank}(A) = m$. The rank of $A$  is at most the smaller dimension, you are calling that $n.$  It follows that  $m=n,$   your matrix is square and invertible

Comment: It was a typo. I corrected it. In the later part of the question, I said only $\mbox{rank}(A) = n$. Thanks for pointing out the typo.

Comment: $P$ is the orthogonal projection onto the span of the columns of $A$. Hence if you choose an orthonormal basis for the span of the columns of $A$, and then complete this basis to an orthonormal  basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$, the matrix of $P$ with respect to this basis is diagonal with an identity block and a 0 block. All your conclusions follow.

Comment: Mason - Thank you, it is very clear.. Can you kindly add how to do a similar construction for M = I - P ?